# Cannot focus near in with Spacemaster Digiscope adapter

Tags: troubleshooting, lens-adapter

I was given an old Bushnell Spacemaster in perfect working condition.  Not knowing what else to do with it, I bought a camera adapter and T-ring mount off ebay, to mount on an old Rebel XT that I found in one of my bins.

I'm not expecting much from an eyepiece projection mount, and indeed, the results aren't stellar.  But it works... to a point.  It cannot focus nearer than about 60-80 meters before running out of travel on the scope's focus knob.  The scope alone can focus much nearer, maybe 5-10m.

Is there anything I can do to improve the near-side focus range on this setup?

[image: Pic of Spacemaster digiscoping setup]

Comment: Bringing the focus nearer is what macro-photography is about. Have you looked at macro adapter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your minimal focus point nearer, you could try technics derived from macro photography, such as an extension tube or close-up lens filters.

I don't know which one will make the correction you want but it probably exists.

Comment: Thanks!  Adding a macro extension tube brought my minimum distance down by about 1/3.  It's not perfect, but it's much more usable.